# How to get the data displayed in Softice's windows to text file

Tags: windows, debugging

I can't copy the information in softice to disk/file. I am aware of IceExt but everytime I execute the command to dump the screen to disk(such as "!DumpScreen \??\c:\test.raw")it crashes my system entirely. When I try to copy with the mouse, the cursor only makes it possible to copy one line. I have already read through the softice manual. I just need a way to retrieve data from softice. Any help would be appreciated. I am using xp professional.

Comment: I don't see anything Delphi-related in this question. (This also looks more like a SoftIce tech support question, since it's the software that's making your system crash.)

Comment: I am using it now to debug delphi applications, however, it can debug programs in other languages as well. "Tech Support"? It has been over four years now since the softare has been discontinunied.

Comment: Yes, I know what SoftIce is (although I didn't realize it was discontinued that long ago). Your question still has nothing to do with Delphi. It also debugs C apps, C++ apps, VB apps, assembly apps, and others (as you said), so there's nothing language-specific to your question (and your question never mentions Delphi).

Comment: +1 I think is a good question. Just remove the delphi tag and add  debugging tag. So the question will get a wider range of programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that no addons are required to accomplish this. Using the command "u cs:eip L 1000" from softice. You will then see a duplicate of the data within softice's screen displayed in the command window.

The u 'unassembles' code at the address cs:eip (the current EIP), the L specifies a length of 1000 bytes, you might need more than 1000 so adjust accordingly. Once you've done this you should exit SoftICE and select File / Save SoftICE History As from Symbol Loader, with any luck the resulting file will contain your code dump.You may have to to use F10 to step through inorder to get the data in softice's history log.

Using this method, I successfully dumped the entire code window and data window. The main drawback to this method is that the resulting text will contain alot of noise(unnecessary data). I haven't figured out how to get around this. This is a adaptation of woodmann's method.

Comment: Additionally softice has to be loaded before windows. My startup setting is "Automatic".